# Remove index.php from magento url in sitemap.xml

Tags: url-rewrite, index.php

We have removed the annoying index.php from all of our urls in magento 1.9.3.8 and the frontend is working beautifully (server rewrites and htaccess properly set up etc.). However, our sitemap.xml is including the index.php portion inevery URL and submitting to google resulting in 404s, obviously. How do we stop the sitemap generator from including the unwanted index.php portion of the url?

Hope someone can help:)

Answer (score 0):

Reindex and generate sitemap once again after removing index.php from url.. 
if your reindex is done properly, it should remove index.php from sitemap as well .